# How read a column or a row from a publicly available Google Sheets using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to read data from a publicly available Google Sheet for example [like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwSU2YVuGea3Dg06yUpUkyhV1Hn-Qf3YshgZkEnJoBo/edit?usp=sharing) using javascript.
I want to read the column of a sheet.

Comment: This might help. https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/reading-google-sheets-data-using-javascript-with-google-sheets-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript isn't necessary, you can just use a regular IMPORTRANGE() function like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1qwSU2YVuGea3Dg06yUpUkyhV1Hn-Qf3YshgZkEnJoBo","Sheet1!A:A")
```

Or with Google Appscript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qwSU2YVuGea3Dg06yUpUkyhV1Hn-Qf3YshgZkEnJoBo')
  .getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A:A').getValues();
  
  Logger.log(array);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]